# Run external javascript script from angular component.html

Tags: angular8

> https://paymentgateway.interswitchgroup.com/paymentgateway/public/js/webpay.js'
>         data-isw-trans-amount='10000'
>         data-isw-customer-ref='1581329633259'
>         data-isw-customer-callback='customCallback' defer>

This block of code is given to me by my payment gateway. it works perfectly on a plain html file.
I added this block to my angular component.html but the script tag is removed by angular. how can i solve this. thanks

Comment: <a data-isw-payment-button data-isw-ref='LEKQI59oW1'>
 <script type='text/javascript' 
     src='https://paymentgateway.interswitchgroup.com/paymentgateway/public/js/webpay.js'
     data-isw-trans-amount='10000'
     data-isw-customer-ref='1581329633259'
     data-isw-customer-callback='customCallback' defer>
 </script>
</a>

Comment: Seems like the script you have posted here is not complete and correct. Can you please post the correct and complete script/code or if you don't have it then ask your payment gateway to get you the same.

Comment: Thanks Varun, see the complete script below:

Comment: <a data-isw-payment-button data-isw-ref='kxa0fv'>
  <script type='text/javascript' 
    src='https://paymentgateway.interswitchgroup.com/paymentgateway/public/js/webpay.js'
    data-isw-trans-amount='10000'
    data-isw-customer-ref='1581429958334'
    data-isw-customer-callback='customCallback'>
  </script>
</a>
<script>
  function customCallback(response){ 
    console.log(response);
  }
</script>

Comment: the script just loads a button on my page, the whole payment is handled by the gateway

Comment: Edit your question and add the above script and clarify your exact query and please post your code, whatever you've tried so far. So that people can help you correcting your code.